# Can I save recorded video in flv format using android?

Tags: android, camera, flv

I am writing a program to record video from Android camera.
I was able to record it and store it as mp4. But I want to record and store it as flv.
Here is my media recorder configuration. Can you tell me how can I change it to record as FLV?

```
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    // mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.initFile().getAbsolutePath());
    mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(50000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(100000);
    // mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(8000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);
    // mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically Android doesn't support `.flv` files for videos. So you have to use some third party video convertor to convert `.mp4` to `.flv` file. Or using [ffmpeg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/) you can able to do this.